# Regex stored in a shell variable doesn't work between double brackets

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell

The below is a small part of a bigger script I'm working on, but the below is giving me a lot of pain which causes a part of the bigger script to not function properly. The intention is to check if the variable has a string value matching `red hat` or `Red Hat`. If it is, then change the variable name to `redhat`. But it doesn't quite match the regex I've used.

```
getos="red hat"
rh_reg="[rR]ed[:space:].*[Hh]at"
if [ "$getos" =~ "$rh_reg" ]; then
  getos="redhat"
fi
echo $getos
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are a multiple things to fix here

- `bash` supports regex pattern matching within its `[[` extended test operator and not within its POSIX standard `[` test operator
- Never quote our regex match string. [`bash` 3.2 introduced a compatibility option `compat31` (under New Features in Bash 1.l)](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/NEWS) which reverts bash regular expression quoting behavior back to 3.1 which supported quoting of the regex string.
- Fix the regex to use `[[:space:]]` instead of just `[:space:]`

So just do

```
getos="red hat"
rh_reg="[rR]ed[[:space:]]*[Hh]at"
if [[ "$getos" =~ $rh_reg ]]; then 
    getos="redhat"
fi;

echo "$getos"
```

or enable the `compat31` option from the extended shell option

```
shopt -s compat31
getos="red hat"
rh_reg="[rR]ed[[:space:]]*[Hh]at"
if [[ "$getos" =~ "$rh_reg" ]]; then 
    getos="redhat"
fi
echo "$getos"
shopt -u compat31
```

But instead of messing with those shell options just use the extended test operator `[[` with an unquoted regex string variable.

Answer (score 4):

There are two issues:

First, replace:

```
rh_reg="[rR]ed[:space:].*[Hh]at"
```

With:

```
rh_reg="[rR]ed[[:space:]]*[Hh]at"
```

A character class like `[:space:]` only works when it is in square brackets.  Also, it appears that you wanted to match zero or more spaces and that is `[[:space:]]*` not `[[:space:]].*`.  The latter would match a space followed by zero or more of anything at all.

Second, replace:

```
[ "$getos" =~ "$rh_reg" ]
```

With:

```
[[ "$getos" =~ $rh_reg ]]
```

Regex matches requires bash's extended test: `[[...]]`.  The POSIX standard test, `[...]`, does not have the feature.  Also, in bash, regular expressions only work if they are unquoted.

#### Examples:

```
$ rh_reg='[rR]ed[[:space:]]*[Hh]at'
$ getos="red Hat"; [[ "$getos" =~ $rh_reg ]] && getos="redhat"; echo $getos
redhat
$ getos="RedHat"; [[ "$getos" =~ $rh_reg ]] && getos="redhat"; echo $getos
redhat
```